# How jQuery $.data() method differs from directly attaching variables to DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do this:

```
$('#someid').data('dataIdentifier', 'someVariable');
```

And in my understanding I can do this:

```
document.getElementById('someid').dataIdentifier = someVariable;
```

What are the pros of using jQuery for this versus raw JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [jquery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to
>   attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from
>   circular references and therefore free
>   from memory leaks. jQuery ensures that
>   the data is removed when DOM elements
>   are removed via jQuery methods, and
>   when the user leaves the page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the jQuery method, but a "pure javascript" approach is to use setAttribute().  setAttribute is the same as what happens when you attach arbitrary data attributes in the html.  You can use getAttribute to read it.

```
document.getElementById('someid').setAttribute("dataIdentifier", "someVariable");
```

One advantage is that it will show up in the innerHTML property, which plain old properties will not.  The disadvantage is you are limited to strings.